# How to create YouTube owner button to open Hangouts?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

How to create button for owner YouTube account for opening streaming live video?

In YouTube, on Creator Studio in "Live Streaming" there is list of events. Each events with status "Live Now" has button "Resume Hangout On Air". This button has property named `data-token` which allows to open Hangouts.

The link looks like: `https://hangouts.google.com/hangouts/_/ytl/[data-token]`

The question is, how I can get `data-token` from YouTube API or maybe there are other ways?

Comment: The same token is used for download mp4 from YouTube Creator Studio

Comment: Have you tried digging around the livestreaming api? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/

Comment: @DaImTo: Yes, but I have not found:(